# After Swift 3 conversion, I can't get rid of error: "Ambiguous use of 'indexOfObject(passingTest:)'"

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, swift3, ios10, ambiguous

I'm using `NSArray`'s indexesOfObjects(passingTest:), but after I converted my code to Swift 3 I get the error: "Ambiguous use of 'indexOfObject(passingTest:)'".
My code below worked fine with Swift 2.3.

```
let indexesOfBubbleConstraints = bubbleConstraints.indexesOfObjects(passingTest: { (constraint, idx, stop) in
        if let view = constraint.firstItem as? UIView{
            return view.tag == usernameTag
        }
        else{
            return false
        }
    })
```

For Swift 3, I also had to cast `constraint` to `AnyObject`, but that doesn't fix the actual problem.

I ended up using `func indexesOfObjects(options: NSEnumerationOptions = [], passingTest: (Any, Int, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Bool)` with an empty Array for options as below. This works, but I still don't understand why I'm getting the "Ambiguous..." error with my original implementation.

```
let indexesOfBubbleConstraints = bubbleConstraints.indexesOfObjects(options: [], passingTest: { (constraint, idx, stop) in
        if let view = (constraint as AnyObject).firstItem as? UIView{
            return view.tag == usernameTag
        }
        else{
            return false
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Objective-C, the two `indexesOf` methods are distinct two methods:

```
- (NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:(BOOL (NS_NOESCAPE ^)(ObjectType obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
- (NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:(NSEnumerationOptions)opts passingTest:(BOOL (NS_NOESCAPE ^)(ObjectType obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
```

And now, Swift 3 import those as ambiguous two methods:

```
@available(iOS 4.0, *)
open func indexesOfObjects(passingTest predicate: (Any, Int, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Bool) -> IndexSet

@available(iOS 4.0, *)
open func indexesOfObjects(options opts: NSEnumerationOptions = [], passingTest predicate: (Any, Int, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Bool) -> IndexSet
```

One is `indexesOfObjects(passingTest:)`, and another is `indexesOfObjects(options:passingTest:)`. And unfortunately, Swift 3 has given a default value for the parameter `options`, which has made a simple call like `bubbleConstraints.indexesOfObjects(passingTest: ...)` ambiguous.

It may be calling

- `indexesOfObjects(passingTest:)`

or

- `indexesOfObjects(options:passingTest:)` with giving default value to `options`

(Swift should not give a default value, if it causes this sort of ambiguity. Better send a bug report.)

In this case, your workaround code, using `indexesOfObjects(options:passingTest:)` should work, but there is another work around:

```
bubbleConstraints.indexesOfObjects(passingTest:) {constraint, idx, stop in
    //...
}
```

The method reference `.indexesOfObjects(passingTest:)` returns the method `indexesOfObjects(passingTest:)` as a closure, and the above expression is calling it.

---

By the way, you better consider using Swift's collection methods, rather than using an `NSArray`s method:

```
let indexesOfBubbleConstraints = bubbleConstraints.enumerated().lazy
    .filter {(idx, constraint) in
        //...
    }.map{$0.offset}
```

Comment: Great detailed answer! I also appreciate your last comment and will definitely do as you recommend.