# Swift - How to get indexes of filtered items of array

Tags: arrays, swift

```
let items: [String] = ["A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "D"]

items.whatFunction("A") // -> [0, 2, 4]
items.whatFunction("B") // -> [1]
```

Does Swift 3 support a function like `whatFunction(_: Element)`?

If not, what is the most efficient logic?

Comment: you can find this way let indexOfA = arr.index(of: "a")

Comment: @BhupatBheda Thank you, but `index(of: Element)` just returns `Int?`. The function that I need should returns `[Int]?`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After Swift 3 conversion, I can't get rid of error: "Ambiguous use of 'indexOfObject(passingTest:)'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569250/after-swift-3-conversion-i-cant-get-rid-of-error-ambiguous-use-of-indexofob)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can create your own extension for arrays.

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func indexes(of element: Element) -> [Int] {
        return self.enumerated().filter({ element == $0.element }).map({ $0.offset })
    }
}
```

You can simply call it like this

```
items.indexes(of: "A") // [0, 2, 4]
items.indexes(of: "B") // [1]
```

Comment: using `.enumerated()` is a bad idea since its not guaranteed to be the index as stated by the apple docu:
`"When you enumerate a collection, the integer part of each pair is a counter for the enumeration, but is not necessarily the index of the paired value."`

Answer (score 50):

You can filter the `indices` of the array directly, it avoids the extra `map`ping.

```
let items = ["A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "D"]
let filteredIndices = items.indices.filter {items[$0] == "A"}
```

or as `Array` extension:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {

    func whatFunction(_ value :  Element) -> [Int] {
        return self.indices.filter {self[$0] == value}
    }

}

items.whatFunction("A") // -> [0, 2, 4]
items.whatFunction("B") // -> [1]
```

or still more generic

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable {

    func whatFunction(_ value :  Element) -> [Index] {
        return self.indices.filter {self[$0] == value}
    }

}
```

Comment: You might as well extend `Collection` since the implementation uses nothing that is specific to arrays.

Comment: @vadian would you like to check https://stackoverflow.com/q/54088250/4601170 and help me please?

Answer (score 33):

You can achieve this by chain of:

1. `enumerated()` - add indexes;
2. `filter()` out unnecessary items;
3. `map()` our indexes.

Example (works in **Swift 3 - Swift 4.x**):

```
let items: [String] = ["A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "D"]  
print(items.enumerated().filter({ $0.element == "A" }).map({ $0.offset })) // -> [0, 2, 4]
```

---

Another way is using `flatMap`, which allows you to check the element and return index if needed in one closure.

Example (works in **Swift 3 - Swift 4.0**):

```
print(items.enumerated().flatMap { $0.element == "A" ? $0.offset : nil }) // -> [0, 2, 4]
```

But since Swift 4.1 `flatMap` that can return non-nil objects become deprecated and instead you should use [`compactMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap).

Example (works since **Swift 4.1**):

```
print(items.enumerated().compactMap { $0.element == "A" ? $0.offset : nil }) // -> [0, 2, 4]
```

---

And the cleanest and the most memory-cheap way is to iterate through array [indices](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/indices) and check if element of array at current index equals to required element.

Example (works in **Swift 3 - Swift 5.x**):

```
print(items.indices.filter({ items[$0] == "A" })) // -> [0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Note that you could also combine filter and map into flatMap, as Julien did, but more details in the answer is good too ;)

Comment: Just another approach is all.  Personally I usually prefer to split filter and map into separate steps if they have different basis, as this does.  If on the other hand one wanted to filter and map on the same property, flatMap makes more sense.

Comment: using `.enumerated()` is a bad idea since its not guaranteed to be the index as stated by the apple docu:
`"When you enumerate a collection, the integer part of each pair is a counter for the enumeration, but is not necessarily the index of the paired value."`

Answer (score 9):

In **Swift 3** and **Swift 4** you can do that:

```
let items: [String] = ["A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "D"]

extension Array where Element: Equatable {

    func indexes(of item: Element) -> [Int]  {
        return enumerated().compactMap { $0.element == item ? $0.offset : nil }
    }
}

items.indexes(of: "A")
```

I hope my answer was helpful

Answer (score 4):

you can use it like that :

```
 let items: [String] = ["A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "D"]

        let indexes = items.enumerated().filter {
            $0.element == "A"
            }.map{$0.offset}

        print(indexes)
```

Answer (score 1):

just copy and paste

```
extension Array {
  func whatFunction(_ ids :  String) -> [Int] {

    var mutableArr = [Int]()
    for i in 0..<self.count {
        if ((self[i] as! String) == ids) {
            mutableArr.append(i)
        }
    }
        return mutableArr 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use that below code:

```
var firstArray = ["k","d","r","r","p","k","b","p","k","k"]
var secondArray = ["k","d","r","s","d","r","b","c"]

let filterArray = firstArray.filter { secondArray.contains($0) }
let filterArray1 = firstArray.filter { !secondArray.contains($0) }
let filterIndex = firstArray.enumerated().filter { $0.element == "k" }.map { $0.offset }
print(filterArray) --> // ["k", "d", "r", "r", "k", "b", "k", "k"]
print(filterArray1) --> // ["p", "p"]
print(filterIndex) --> // [0, 5, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be a way too

```
// MARK: - ZIP: Dictionary like

let words = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
let numbers = 1...words.count

for (word, number) in zip(words, numbers) {
    print("\n\(word): \(number)")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For example finding the indices of p_last values that are in inds1 array: (swift 4+)

```
let p_last = [51,42]
let inds1 = [1,3,51,42,4]
let idx1 = Array(inds1.filter{ p_last.contains($0) }.indices)
```

idx1 = [0,1]